# Rails select Empty method?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, select

I have the following select in a helper for my Rails app:

```
 def unit_select
    Unit.all.map{|unit| unit.calls.empty? ? [unit.unit_name, unit.id] : ["#{unit.unit_name} (on call)", unit.id] }
  end
```

What this does is look for a unit that has a call and if that unit has a call append (on call) next to the unit in a form.  The problem I'm seeing with this is when it goes to look for unit.calls.empty? it's taking into account call records with a status of "closed" which should not be taken into account.

Is there another method I can use (or write) that will allow me to look at unit.calls with passing whether or not the call is in call_status open?

Answer (score 0):

In your Unit model you can override the empty? method on the calls association:

```
class Unit < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :calls do
    def empty?
      self.where(:call_status => :open).any?
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: This works perfect, however it overwrites the empty? method in case I need to use it somewhere else.  I tried to rename it to assigned? and use it in my helper but it fails.  Is this a constraint in Rails that only allows empty? as a method?

Comment: nope, you can use any method named you'd like there should not be an problem.

Comment: Actually, strike that.  When I close a call it sets call_status "closed" and in the form the units still show up with (on call)

Comment: I didn't understand - Are you still having the problem?

Comment: Yes, sorry.  Still having the problem.  When I put this in my model for unit.rb I get a stack level too deep when placed in the association.  If I try it anywhere else in the model it does nothing.  I've also tried this on the call.rb side of the association with no luck.

Comment: This is very strange, I successfully implemented it and everything works fine. The problem is probably somewhere else in your code.

Comment: So it should be included within the association right?  Here's what my association looks like from the unit side:has_many :call_units
  has_many :calls, through: :call_units

Comment: I'm using a has_many with a join table so maybe that's why the stack level too deep is showing up?

Comment: Including this in my helper works.  unit.calls.where(call_status: "open").empty?  I have an open scope that does the same thing but gives me wrong # of args 0..3.